# Как удалить только определённую последовательность тегов в javascript?

Tags: javascript

После парсинга получаю несколько таблиц типа

```
<div><table><tbody><tr><td>аааа</td><td><div>бббб</div></td></tr><tr><td>вввв</td><td><div>гггг</div></td></tr></tbody></table></div><div><table><tbody><tr><td>дддд</td><td><div>ееее</div></td></tr></tbody></table></div><div><table><tbody><tr><td>жжжж</td><td>1</td></tr><tr><td>зззз</td><td>2</td></tr><tr><td>Площадь(кв.м)</td><td>43</td></tr></tbody></table></div><div><table><tbody><tr><td>Мебель</td><td><div>диван</div><div>зеркало</div><div>кроватьдвуспальная</div><div>наборплетеноймебели</div><div>прикроватныетумбочки</div><div>столиккофейный</div><div>шкаф-купе</div></td></tr><tr><td>Оборудование</td><td><div>кондиционер</div><div>мини-холодильник</div><div>телевизорЖК</div><div>телефон</div><div>чайныйнаборпосуды</div></td></tr><tr><td>Санузел</td><td><div>биде</div><div>сванной</div><div>тапочки</div><div>туалетныепринадлежности</div><div>фен</div><div>халат</div></td></tr><tr><td>Сервис</td><td><div>Wi-Fiбесплатно</div><div>сменаполотенец</div><div>сменапостельногобелья</div><div>уборканомера</div></td></tr></tbody></table></div>
```

Как возможно склеить эти таблицы путём удаления регулярным выражением последовательности тегов `</tbody></table></div><div><table><tbody>`. Если именно эту последовательность тегов удалить - таблицы склеиваются. Как это программно сделать - не соображу.

Comment: Тут регулярка не нужна... надо просто взять подстроку до этих символов и подстроку после этих символов и сконкатенировать (если этот код - одна строка, а не отформатированный html, каковым сделали ребята-редакторы)))

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, можно обычным `.replace`

Comment: @Grundy да, я как раз про него вспомнил (только replaceAll скорее )

Comment: дубликаты где-то [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+replaceAll)

Answer (score 0):

```js
let html = '<div><table><tbody><tr><td>аааа</td><td><div>бббб</div></td></tr><tr><td>вввв</td><td><div>гггг</div></td></tr></tbody></table></div><div><table><tbody><tr><td>дддд</td><td><div>ееее</div></td></tr></tbody></table></div><div><table><tbody><tr><td>жжжж</td><td>1</td></tr><tr><td>зззз</td><td>2</td></tr><tr><td>Площадь(кв.м)</td><td>43</td></tr></tbody></table></div><div><table><tbody><tr><td>Мебель</td><td><div>диван</div><div>зеркало</div><div>кроватьдвуспальная</div><div>наборплетеноймебели</div><div>прикроватныетумбочки</div><div>столиккофейный</div><div>шкаф-купе</div></td></tr><tr><td>Оборудование</td><td><div>кондиционер</div><div>мини-холодильник</div><div>телевизорЖК</div><div>телефон</div><div>чайныйнаборпосуды</div></td></tr><tr><td>Санузел</td><td><div>биде</div><div>сванной</div><div>тапочки</div><div>туалетныепринадлежности</div><div>фен</div><div>халат</div></td></tr><tr><td>Сервис</td><td><div>Wi-Fiбесплатно</div><div>сменаполотенец</div><div>сменапостельногобелья</div><div>уборканомера</div></td></tr></tbody></table></div>';
let cutString = '</tbody></table></div><div><table><tbody>';

document.body.innerHTML = html.replaceAll(cutString, '');
```

```css
table td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Comment: data () {
    return {
      substr: '</tbody></table></div><div><table><tbody>'
    }
  },
  methods: {
    goFix () {
      this.rooms.forEach(async (item) => {
        const desc = item.description.replace(this.substr, '')
        console.log(desc)
      })
    }
Я сам удивлён, но не работает.

Comment: @steelpear этот код, оторванный от контекста, ни о чём не говорит. Предлагаю создать новый вопрос с указанием воспроизводимого примера (https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)  и контекста (https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), в котором нужно что-то починить. В текущем вопросе, увы или не увы, но дан рабочий ответ на предоставленную проблему

Comment: @steelpear к тому же ты применяешь replace, а я в ответе написал replaceAll